# Как пользоваться классом DerivatveStructure?

Tags: java, apache, математика

Мне нужно задать полином 2-го порядка от 3 неизвестных, взять от него производную 1-го порядка, а так же найти значения этих функций на некотором наборе точек. Я нашёл  [Apache Commons Math framework](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/index.html), который является мощным инструментом при работе с математическим анализом. Этот фреймворк так же поддерживает нахождение производных, что мне и нужно. Проблема заключается в том, что [документация](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/analysis.html#a4.7_Differentiation) не дала ответы на все мои вопросы, а именно:

1. Как создать функцию, которую я буду дифференциировать?
2. Как найти значение функции (и дифф.), в конкретных точках?

Возможно, этот вопрос для кого-то тривиален, но меня он поставил в тупик.
Если это возможно, я бы хотел увидеть алгоритм, который помог бы мне разобраться как "строить" функции и брать от них производные.
Пример кода приветствуется.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```
int params = 1;
int order = 3;
double xRealValue = 2.5;
DerivativeStructure x = new DerivativeStructure(params, order, 0, xRealValue);
DerivativeStructure y = f(x);
System.out.println("y    = " + y.getValue();
System.out.println("y'   = " + y.getPartialDerivative(1);
System.out.println("y''  = " + y.getPartialDerivative(2);
System.out.println("y''' = " + y.getPartialDerivative(3);
```

[Источник по Дифференциации](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/analysis.html#a4.7_Differentiation)

Comment: А вот и в целом справочник: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/index.html

Comment: Николай, мне нужно составить функцию от 3 переменных, а в примере - от 1. И что такое f? Вы его нигде не объявили.